# document.getElementById not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with `document.getElementByID` in Mozilla. In the IE and Chrome my code is working well.

I have written the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(x, y) {
var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    text1.innerText += x[i]; // prints 12345
  }
   text1.innerText += "\ny: " + y; // prints y: 1,2,3,4,5
  }
</script>


 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
<div id="text1"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Can any one tell why this doesn't work in FireFox?

Comment: Not working how? I can see your ASP code (which doesn't help me), but where is the trigger to `test` function? I am asking because **all browsers** support `getElementById`.

Comment: `.innerText` is non standard. Don't use it. use `.textContent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's the call to `getElementById` that's the problem — if it is, then you didn't give enough detail — but I can tell you that Firefox and some other browsers do not implement `innerText`.  For those browsers, you need to work with `textContent` or text nodes directly.

You can find out whether `textContent` is supported or not using feature detection:

```
var textContentOrInnerText = "textContent" in document.body 
                               ? "textContent" : "innerText";
```

Then, you use this variable for the property access in your code:

```
text1[textContentOrInnerText] += x[i];
```

Feel free to shorten the variable to something you feel more comfortable with.  Note that there are some minor differences in behaviour between both properties, but mostly you won't notice them.

`textContent` is the standards behaviour which is why I test for that first in my code.

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` is not referenced anywhere in the DOM standard, therefore it's non-standard and an IE only hack.

Please use [`.textContent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-node-textcontent) to get the text content.

For browser support either use a library or a [shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim)

Comment: @Vivekh as mentioned use a library or a shim for browser support.